# Virus on an Android Phone from viewing Goolge Images

Tags: security

so earlier this evening I browsed through some playboy images on Google Images. I have to do a project on Women as a Sex Symbol. Now I just viewed the Images on Google Images without clicking any image to get a preview. Is there a danger that I could get a virus by just viewing Images of scantily-clad women or other content such as logos or cars or something like that. Only viewing the google images  and not clicking on a preview and all this on my android phone.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine. Browse away. Enjoy! ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just wantes the assurance of someone else.:)